# Return a list of keywords associated with a place id in Google API?

Tags: google-api, google-places-api, google-search-api

Google API allows to retrieve a list of places based on [Text Search](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-text) in an area and the place_id initially retrieved can then be used with [Place Details](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details) to get more information. However Google doesn't provide relevant keywords associated with this place. I am wondering if given a known place_id, it is possible to search all the associated keywords that would have return this result in a Google search otherwise.

For instance, a Text Search for "**Mexican**" Restaurant in Chelsea would return a number of places including place_id X. If you search for "**Tacos**" in Chelsea, it may return a number of places also including **place_id X**. Is there a way for me to query details about **place_id X** and return keywords "Mexican" and "Tacos" ?

If not, **is there a cost-effective workaround?** I thought about creating a master keywords database of 1000+ terms relevant to my market and then query every term in all the areas my app intends to serve and associate each keyword search with place ids but it may cost me a lot vs. querying these details with known place ids directly.

Thank you!